# MANY FACEBOOK SHARE buttons in the same page?

Tags: html, django, facebook, share, facebook-like

I implemented the facebook share button in my page using javascript, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#share_button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                name: "{{ user_name }}'s FOF",
                link: "https://www.example.com/uploader/{{current_fof}}/share_fof/",
                picture: imgsArray[0].src,
                caption: window.location.href,
                description: 'This FOF was taken by {{ user_name }}',
                message: ''
            });     
        });
    });
</script>


<div class="share"> <img src = "{{ STATIC_URL }}images/share_facebook.png" id="share_button" type='button_count'></div>
```

It is working pretty well but now I'd like to put many posts within the same page and use a different share button for each post (very FB share button shall have **a different link, title and image)**. Any ideas?

It worked with the like button, using the FB API:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.example.com/uploader/{{current_fof}}/share_fof/" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
```

But how to do a similar thing with the share_button? Any idea?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give each of your "share" button a different id and alter the other options(different link, title and image) for each item.
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#share_button1').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                name: "{{ user_name }}'s FOF",
                link: "https://mysite.com/uploader/{{current_fof}}/share_fof/",
                picture: imgsArray[0].src,
                caption: window.location.href,
                description: 'This FOF was taken by {{ user_name }}',
                message: ''
            });     
        });
        $('#share_button2').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                name: "{{ user_name }}'s FOF",
                link: "https://mysite.com/uploader/{{current_fof}}/share_fof/",
                picture: imgsArray[0].src,
                caption: window.location.href,
                description: 'This FOF was taken by {{ user_name }}',
                message: ''
            });     
        });          
        $('#share_button3').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                name: "{{ user_name }}'s FOF",
                link: "https://mysite.com/uploader/{{current_fof}}/share_fof/",
                picture: imgsArray[0].src,
                caption: window.location.href,
                description: 'This FOF was taken by {{ user_name }}',
                message: ''
            });     
        });
});
</script>
```

The buttons could be:

```
<div class="share"> <img src = "{{ STATIC_URL }}images/share_facebook.png" id="share_button1" type='button_count'></div>  
<div class="share"> <img src = "{{ STATIC_URL }}images/share_facebook.png" id="share_button2" type='button_count'></div>  
<div class="share"> <img src = "{{ STATIC_URL }}images/share_facebook.png" id="share_button3" type='button_count'></div>
```

Comment: where does the FB comes from=?

Comment: @mallix please check this question , can you give a help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283576/many-facebook-share-buttons-in-one-page

Comment: @EgzontinaK that link is broken.. I also need to know how to get that FB object.

Comment: I know this is old, but FYI - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Comment: Also, this solution doesn't work anymore. Facebook has deprecated these features. See "deprecated parameters" at the bottom: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog