# how to share a div or a part of a html page via facebook?

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I know this question has been asked several times in the past but as FB changed how its SDK  works in Javascript, I guess this question is back again.

I have a html page, and I need to allow the users to share certain parts of the page (a div or an image) in Facebook using a Facebook share button.

According to some answers given back in 2013 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111177/many-facebook-share-buttons-in-the-same-page)), it seems that the the FB.ui function can be customized. I tried and it did not work. Only the meta tag in my html page was shown.

I understand from Facebook developer documentation that the SDK only crawls meta tag in the html page (I stand to be corrected). I can't put the parts that I want users to share in the meta tag because the parts change based on users' interaction.

I appreciate any advice. Thanks.

The FB.ui code that I found and tried but failed:

```
FB.ui(
{
    method: "feed",
    name: "testing",
    link: "put a url here",
    picture: "put a jpg file here",
    caption: "testing",
    description: put in the class of a div here,
    message: put in the class of another div here
});
```

Comment: Yes we crawl the url you share and you have to add the right og-tags

Comment: yes @WizKid that's my question here. I want the SDK box to show a div or an image that I can't put in the og-tags, because the div/image changes based on users response. And the page is a html page, meaning I also can't change the meta tag dynamically. I know php page can do that.

Comment: I know that was your question. My answer was that it is not possible

Comment: I wonder how quizzes like this one on Buzzfeed http://www.buzzfeed.com/deenashanker/man-vs-food#" can make the users to share their results on Facebook?

Comment: Generating a unique url for each result is my guess